# Android listview(recyclerView) how to cover first cell like Google I/O app or play store

Tags: android, android-listview, google-play

A picture may tells what I want:
I donnt have enough Reputation so please check this link.
http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/005yyi5Jjw1ej4gsxduwej31h70h245u.jpg
When you scroll the list up, the image will scroll up in different speed in the background too. 
Play store and Google I/O 2014 app have this effect.
use a recyclerView and custom layout manager?
Thanks! 
Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have already noticed, but source code for I/O app had been released. 
https://github.com/google/iosched

Answer (score 0):

See this article:
http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/

and this answer: [Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview/26573338#26573338)

It is using `setTranslationY`, but you can similarly use `setHeight` like on the image you provided.

The hand (and the space above his head) disappears gradually because the height changes and the image in the `ImageView` is `centerCrop`.
I'm not sure if this is the exact code, but looks close enough: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_session_detail.xml#L43