# Aligning a RecyclerView below a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout called "footer" I want to place below my `RecyclerView` (a new type of list introduced in API 21).

1. The `recyclerview` will probably want to have a `"match_parent"` height to efficiently use memory (avoid unecessary calculation).
2. I shouldn't have the `recyclerview` first because then it will take up the whole screen and the footer wont be visible.
3. Since the `recyclerview` comes second the `linearlayout` shouldn't have a `"match_parent"` height, because then the `recyclerview` won't be seen, and I don't need the footer to stretch anyways.

So I have the `linearlayout` `"footer"`, a height first in my root `relativelayout`, then the `recyclerview` will be `"match_parent"`, and specified above the "footer":

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addTaskImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addTaskRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:background="@color/White">
        </EditText>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/paletteRed"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/taskET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/Red" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/paletteOrange"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/taskET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/paletteRed"
            android:background="@color/Orange" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/paletteGreen"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/taskET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/paletteOrange"
            android:background="@color/Green" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/paletteRoyalBlue"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/taskET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/paletteGreen"
            android:background="@color/RoyalBlue" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/palettePurple"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/taskET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/paletteRoyalBlue"
            android:background="@color/Purple" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/taskET"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/palettePurple"
            android:background="@color/SkyBlue"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:text="@string/submit">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/tasksRV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know this is a layout issue only because if I remove the footer my `recyclerview` is displayed.  What is my misunderstanding of layouts above?

Comment: Do you have a problem? Can you describe it?

Comment: All that shows is the footer near the top of the screen, instead of the recycler view, then the footer below it.

Comment: You just forgot to add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your footer layout, so to anchor it to the bottom of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: hmm, I thought since I said match parent, above footer that would have taken care of it automatically, but it doesnt.  thanks.

Comment: I made my comment an answer, so you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Comment: if you want the linear layout as a footer take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/2127203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to add this line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

to your footer layout, so to anchor it to the bottom of the RelativeLayout.