# Recycler View with Button below it, Layout Crashing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to have a `Button` at the bottom of a `RecyclerView`, but the app keeps on crashing without any errors. I have been trying to find a way around it for a long while now, and have been through the related SO questions. Here is my xml snippet:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scan_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ScanButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:onClick="scanNow"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rv" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[This](https://github.com/sanke-t/BookScanProjectD) question says to add //android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"// to linear layout but Android Studio declares it as useless for Linear Layout. I also tried switching to relative layout and still no progress.

[PROJECT ON GITHUB](https://github.com/sanke-t/BookScanProjectD)

Please help.

Logcat(Error):

```
roid.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    11-29 11:39:44.411    2643-2643/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    11-29 11:39:44.411    2643-2643/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
    11-29 11:39:50.054    2670-2670/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    11-29 11:39:50.054    2670-2670/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
    11-29 11:39:50.096    2670-2678/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
    11-29 11:39:52.722    2679-2679/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.sanket.d, PID: 2679
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    11-29 11:42:54.613    2718-2718/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    11-29 11:42:54.614    2718-2718/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
    11-29 11:42:59.985    2746-2746/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    11-29 11:42:59.985    2746-2746/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
    11-29 11:43:00.099    2756-2763/? E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
    11-29 11:43:03.459    2756-2756/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.sanket.d, PID: 2756
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    11-29 11:43:07.420    1233-1275/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'bd828ef com.example.sanket.d/com.example.sanket.d.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    11-29 12:12:19.185    2783-2783/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    11-29 12:12:19.185    2783-2783/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
    11-29 12:12:19.212    2783-2792/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
    11-29 12:12:19.609    2795-2795/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    11-29 12:12:19.609    2795-2795/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
    11-29 12:12:19.667    2795-2803/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
    11-29 12:12:23.835    2804-2804/com.example.sanket.d E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.sanket.d, PID: 2804
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    11-29 12:14:05.880    1557-1724/android.process.acore E/DictionaryBackupAgent﹕ Couldn't read from the cursor
    11-29 12:14:06.280    2897-2897/android.process.media E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 38 frames from WAL file /data/user/0/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db-wal
    11-29 12:14:06.290    2897-2911/android.process.media E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 152 frames from WAL file /data/user/0/com.android.providers.media/databases/internal.db-wal
    11-29 12:14:10.739    2830-2839/com.android.dialer E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:10.740    2830-2839/com.android.dialer E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:10.740    2830-2839/com.android.dialer E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:10.878    2846-2855/com.android.calendar E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:10.879    2846-2855/com.android.calendar E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:10.879    2846-2855/com.android.calendar E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:10.999    2864-2873/com.android.sharedstoragebackup E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:11.000    2864-2873/com.android.sharedstoragebackup E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:11.000    2864-2873/com.android.sharedstoragebackup E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:11.119    2879-2888/com.android.browser E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:11.119    2879-2888/com.android.browser E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
    11-29 12:14:11.120    2879-2888/com.android.browser E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691357/aligning-a-recyclerview-below-a-linearlayout
[PROJECT ON GITHUB][1]
```

Comment: Please post logcat crash logs

Comment: Also add you activity class code, because layout looks good.

Comment: Avoid posting long logs in SO. Post it somewhere else and link it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I see now. The problem is not in your XML layout. You should initialize your RecyclerView from code. You should specify Layout manager for it:

`final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);` `layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);` `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Still not working man. Here is the project- https://github.com/sanke-t/BookScanProjectD MainActivity is the one with this view.

Comment: Looked through your code, You are setting layout manager in onActivityResult method. Move it to onCreate, after

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tested, no crash