# recycleview scroll with other view at same time

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

i have recycleview and in top i have one view which includes textview .

my problem is when scroll up that text-view always at top and only recycle-view scroll .. is any way i can scroll both . i don't want to use view type in recycle-view as it already use for some other purpose

my XML

```
 <Rel layout>
 <text-view id="text"/>
 <recycle-view below="text" />
```

so how textview will go up and down with recycle-view scroll  can any give small snippet for this

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756624/how-to-make-recyclerview-header-not-sticky

Comment: You will have to add your header as the first item in the RecyclerView

Comment: as i said i cant use viewType

Comment: can we use nestedscroll ?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: You can implement scrollListener of recyclerview and on onscroll of recyclerview scroll the textview too.. like parallax effect

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to keep the TextView separate from the RecyclerView, wrap them in a `NestedScrollView` instead:

```
<NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView />
      <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

When you set up your RecyclerView, you will probably want to call `RecyclerView#setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` otherwise the RV may consume some scrolling inside the parent (which you don't want).

**NOTE**: This approach makes the tradeoff that the RV will be forced to layout all of its views, losing the recycling benefit. The correct approach would be to properly dedicate a `viewType` to the RV for this header TextView and not deal with wrapping it inside additional ViewGroups.

Comment: even this remain at top .  my this view is subvivew of parsent view which have coridnt layout with collasping tollbar

Comment: Edited. The NSV should have a single child. It's actually important to know you were trying to do this with CoordinatorLayout because regular ScrollView does not work at all inside a CoordinatorLayout, only NSV does.

Comment: with this my RecyclerView is not scrollable i have to five fix heigth

Comment: You need to fully explain the context of the problem and desired solution. Include all of the relevant viewgroups used/nested because they will of course affect how the final UI behaves.

The original question did not mention CoordinatorLayout etc, so I believe this answer technically satisfies the question unless the question is edited to be more specific.

Comment: In case of nestedscrollview you'll have to layout all of the views inside RV, so all benefits from RV (recycling) are gone.

Comment: @dilix this is true, but the answer addresses the OP's problem with the tradeoff that RV will layout all of the RV views. If that is unacceptable, then the correct approach is to allocate a dedicated `viewType` and put it in the RV. I'll edit the answer to note this tradeoff.