# Two recycler view in same layout as in flipboard app

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview, flipboard

I want to use a `RecyclerView`(list like) below another `RecyclerView`(Grid like) as in flipboard

[image]

I tried two `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` with wrap content but nothing is showing.

I can able to see two views if it is placed in linear layout and equal weight is added to it. But that does not look like this app View.

This is my layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/parent_category_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/default_small_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/category_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that they use two `ListView`s (or `ListView` + `GridView`).

I think they use a `ListView` ( the one in the bottom) and they add a custom **Header** to this list (the one in the top), which look like a `GridView`.

Or if they use a `Recyclerview`, they can achieve this by using a different layout in the adapter for the first item.

[image]

**PS:** it's not recommended to use two scrollable view inside each other (like `Recyclerview` inside `ScrollView`).

Comment: Thanks, But i have a question. Is it possible to set/change the layout of recycler view dynamically in the adapter?

Comment: Yes! you can for example add a *type* to your model, and depending on this type you inflate the desired layout... take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/4224337

Comment: So in adapter i wil again set recyclerView.setLayoutManaget(... ) right

Comment: no, set layout param where you initialized recycler view

Comment: No, you don't need to set again the LayoutManager of your RecyclerView.

Comment: I tried in onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int position) by checking the position i setting gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(1). but no luck :(

Comment: i am getting these error : IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Comment: SpanCount should be 2 not 1, and please refer to the above link to know the changes that you should make in your adapter.

Comment: @Rami, then how to display the heading 'Categories' in the above picture.

Comment: Its a sectionned ListView http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a really simple way to achieve the desired layout with just one `RecyclerView`!

The key is using a `GridLayoutManager` and its `SpanSizeLookup`.
First of all define your GridLayoutManager like this:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, spanCount);
```

where spanCount is the maximum amount of spans/columns you want to have. In your case, spanCount should be **2**;

Now you need a way to tell this layoutManager how many spans an item should span.
A simple way would be to use a viewtype/ViewHolder for items that should span just one column and another one for items that span the whole width.

Let's assume you define the viewtype for grid-items as `VIEWTYPE_GRID_ITEM` and the viewtype for standard listitems as `VIEWTYPE_LIST_ITEM`.
You can then use these viewtypes to tell the layoutManager when to use just one span:

```
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position){
        return adapter.getItemViewType(position) == VIEWTYPE_GRID_ITEM ? 1 : spanCount;
    }
});
```

Finally, set the layoutManager to your RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

And that's it!

Comment: Great to hear that! It would be good if you'd flag this answer as the correct solution to help other readers find it quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

In android we are advise to use only one scrollable view at time , if you want to use one scrollable view inside other one refer below links.

1)[Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

2) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view)

Comment: Thanks, But if we set wrap content to recycler view the view is not showing.

Comment: Yes , for this we have to set some height to them