# Prevent CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse if not needed

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

With the project [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) updated.

Into the detail of cheese, I remove 2 cards (to have only one). Is there a way to prevent the collapsing of the toolbar that show a blank space?

[image]

Comment: I didn't really find a solution, however I'm now using https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout and I don't have this issue (since the implementation is different)

Comment: what did you do about it ?

Comment: This is what you need [custom scrolling view behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774587/9947711)

Answer (score 37):

To implement such behaviour in [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) example just modify `android:layout_height` param of the NestedScrollView to `wrap_content`.
It will prevent scrolling by content if it is small enough to fit on the screen.

And to prevent scrolling by `CollapsingToolbarLayout` you should programmatically set `layout_scrollFlags` parameter to the `AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP` value.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407936/change-layout-scrollflags-programmatically-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout/33217085#33217085) described how you can do this.

Comment: Or in xml add ``app:layout_scrollFlags="snap" `` to the CollapsingToolbarLayout tag

Comment: then nested scrollview is good but the collapse toolbar is still scrollable

Comment: layout_scrollFlags is not working.
use this workaround for disable CollapsingToolbarLayout scrolling.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750707/3094065
it is true way and really works! )

Comment: In my case, `wrap_content` resolves the problem. The layout has `AppBarLayout` and `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code for this:

```
   public static void stopScroll() {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsing_toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    toolbarLayoutParams.setScrollFlags(0);
    collapsing_toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbar.getLayoutParams();
    appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(null);
    appbar.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
}

public static void startScroll() {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsing_toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    toolbarLayoutParams.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
    collapsing_toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbar.getLayoutParams();
    appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.Behavior());
    appbar.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Works for me as I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

In xml I have used property

`app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"` in  `<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

and following in the activity

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 toolbar.setTitle(null);
 toolbar.setCollapsible(false);
```

It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

A data-binding solution inspired by @Vishal's answer

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:enableCollapsingScroll="@{listItems.size > 0}"
            ... />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

```kotlin
    @BindingAdapter("app:enableCollapsingScroll")
    fun setCollapsingToolbarLayoutScrollEnabled(collapsingToolbarLayout: CollapsingToolbarLayout, enabled: Boolean?) {
        val lp = collapsingToolbarLayout.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
        if (enabled.orFalse()) {
            lp.scrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL or AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED
        } else {
            lp.scrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP
        }
        collapsingToolbarLayout.layoutParams = lp
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code, to initially collapes the bar:

_appbar.setExpanded(false);

```
   AppBarLayout _appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    _appbar.setExpanded(false);
```

here is the layout xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />





    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

the reference is: [AppBarLayout.setExpanded(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean))

Comment: The question is how to prevent collapsing

Answer (score 0):

```
  AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) activityUserGroupProfleBinding.collapsingToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        if (logic) {
            params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
        } else {
            params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);
        }
        activityUserGroupProfleBinding.collapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```