# AppbarLayout Height & Scrolling

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am using CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout. I have set `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`. In NestedScrollView, I have LinearLayout which height vary based on TextView Content size.

**Problem:** When I have big content in TextView say 100 lines then my toolbar collapsed as expected but if I have say 2-3 lines in the TextView  then toolbar still collapsed where as my page does not scroll.

**Help:** Please help in fixing this page so that if my page has enough scrollable content then only toolbar should be collapsed otherwise it should not collapse.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Aditya, could you please eleborate your objective.
You want the AppBar to be collapsed even if the content of NestedScrollView is small and fits the screen height?

Comment: Thanks for commenting!! If page content is more then only appbar should collapse. OR you can say "As much page is scrollable due to content that much appbar should collapse"

Comment: it looks like you a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288179/prevent-collapsingtoolbarlayout-collapse-if-not-needed/33217312#33217312).
 So maybe the proposed solution will be useful for you