# Minimum height CollapsibleToolbar in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm having an issue using `AppBarLayout` with `CollapsibleToolbar`.

**Picture 1** is my initial state. The dark blue is my `AppBarLayout`

**Picture 2** is in case my content height is bigger than the screen. The `CollapsibleToolbar` collapses and the content keep scrolling

**Picture 3** is my problem. My content is smaller than the screen size. but since the `CollapsibleToolbar` has the flag `exitUntilCollapsed` the content keeps scrolling all the way up.

I tried many ways of using `minHeight` in both the layout and the toolbar with no success. as well as other scroll flags

Question: Is there a way of stopping my `AppBarLayout` or `CollapsibleToolbar` from scrolling if the height of my content is shown on the screen?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse if not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288179/prevent-collapsingtoolbarlayout-collapse-if-not-needed)