# Plain header text inside recycler view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android and i am trying to achieve the result shown in attached screenshot. I am using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) to get the same result and to manage the positioning of items i am using [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html). My problem is i am able to make the grid but i do not have any idea how to add text between two grids in recyclerview like the text "What's Hot" in the screenshot.

[image]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id = "@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgsrc"
    android:src="@drawable/close" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class CategoryRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
List<CatetoryListModel> data = Collections.emptyList();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public CategoryRecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<CatetoryListModel> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_custom_row,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view,context);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

   // StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
  //  layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

    CatetoryListModel current = data.get(position);
    //holder.title.setText(current.getCategoryName());
   // holder.desp.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.getImgSrc());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView title;
    TextView desp;
    ImageView icon;
    Context cntxt;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView,Context c) {
        super(itemView);
        cntxt = c;
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
       // title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
      //  desp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        icon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgsrc);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(cntxt,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
    recycler = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    adapter = new CategoryRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
    gridView = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
 //   recycler.setHasFixedSize(false);
   // recycler.addItemDecoration(new Divider);
    gridView.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {

        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if(position == 0)
                return 2;

            return 1;
        }
    });

 //   gridView.setSpanCount(2);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(gridView);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

public static List<CatetoryListModel> getData(){
List<CatetoryListModel> data =new ArrayList<>();
 int[] icons = {R.drawable.banner,R.drawable.sale,R.drawable.ethnic,R.drawable.kurti,R.drawable.sarees};
    String[] titles = {"CLOSE","CLOSE","HELP","PLAY","SETTING"};
    String[] desp = {"CLOSE","CLOSE CLOSE","HELP CLOSE","PLAY CLOSE","SETTING CLOSE"};
    for(int i=0;i<icons.length;i++){

        CatetoryListModel singleItem = new CatetoryListModel(titles[i],desp[i],icons[i]);
        data.add(singleItem);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another type of item (say HEADER_TYPE) in the recycler View. Right now all your items in recycler view are of same type.

You can override `public int getItemViewType(int position)` function to return the appropriate type based on the position and in `onCreateViewHolder` you can inflate a different layout for HEADER_TYPE items and normal items.

Here is an example: [Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
 I have lots of text which should be in between the grids and also these are non clickable. Can i use the different HEADER_TYPE for this?

Comment: Also can i add a dot pageindicator/ViewPagerIndicator
 inside the recycler view?