# RecyclerView with SwipeRefreshLayout is not working consistently

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I know similar question is asked many times but it couldn't solve my issue. So I am asking here. I have a recyclerView with swiperefresh layout. I have used this code

```
recyclerView1.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                //super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                try {
                    int firstPos = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (refreshLayout != null) {
                        if (firstPos > 0) {
                            refreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            activity.refreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                            if (recyclerView1.getScrollState() == 1)
                                if (activity.refreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                                    recyclerView1.stopScroll();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });
```

to differentiate the scroll of recyclerView and swipe refresh layout. But I have added a header to this recyclerView using this [[Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview]). Now the header height in the recyclerview is too big so in small devices

```
int firstPos = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

is returning 0 when only half of the header is visible. And it is enabling swiperefreshlayout. So I can't see the whole header in recyclerView. Can anybody help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new PullRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            // start refresh
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                         }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });


    recList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        }
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                refreshLayout.setEnabled(llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does this code do? Don't just copy paste code, add a little explanation.