# How to make the first row of RecyclerView contains custom number of items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, staggeredgridlayout

[What I want to reach at the end, a view like this image, Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1rEz.png)

- I have `RecyclerView` and I am using `GridLayoutManager`.
- I want to have 5 items of the list in the first row.
- The rest of the rows should contain 6 items per each row.
- Items in the first row has a bigger sizes than the others.

I tried `gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(...)`

Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579800/best-way-to-implement-header-over-a-recyclerview-using-a-grid-layout

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this:  
`@Override public int getSpanSize(int position) {  
        return (position == 0) ? 3 : 1;  
    }`  
  
but it is just making the first item takes space of 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library Called **[Groupi](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie)** which makes working with **RecyclerView** very easy. See [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/37f2d500453ef5c5441c7f68bc69ad1145460a9a/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f6566744f4530762e676966)  for example.

Comment: unfortunately it is not the same behavior.

Comment: @Ahmed, The GIF in the link is not the only "behavior" you can do with the Library, You can customize any item you want to include in Recyclerview. Read the doc [link] 
(https://github.com/lisawray/groupie), I left out the code how to do it because its a little verbose