# RecyclerView within a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm wanting to add a RecyclerView into a ScrollView so I can easily add a header to the RecyclerView.

I've called setAutoMeasureEnabled(true) ([part of the recently announced changes to the RecyclerView](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)) to the LayoutManager but the result is no recycling of child views.

If there are 10,000 items in my adapter, 10,000 views are created...

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Nesting scrolling views is always problematic. Maybe try one of those solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview

Comment: @DavidMedenjak - I think that is why `NestedScrollView` was created.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak adding a header using the adapter is one way for sure but with the addition of the *setAutoMeasureEnabled* method I was curious to see if a ScrollView could be used to simplify this.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did not say this wasn't possible, I'm just trying to avoid a possible XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on a related Android issue and this is not how this should be used:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=74772

For any readers the advise is to NOT used a RecyclerView within a ScrollView with setAutoMeasureEnabled(true).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, 10.000 items will be 10.000 view created, to prevent this will need a Paging solution and a Endless RecyclerView

Some references:
https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView