# RecyclerView below LinearLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

For my app I have to show a list of data (100 items) in a fragment and there has to be some text and an image above it. This all has to be in a single ScrollView so you can scroll in the whole page and not just in the list of data.

When I don't use the ScrollView it's only possible to scroll in the RecyclerView but the user needs to scroll over the complete page.

```
  Scrollview
|------------|
|            |
|    text    |  <-- LinearLayout
|            |
|------------|
|            |
|    list    |  <-- RecyclerView, longer than screen height
|            |
|------------|
```

So how can I make it this way without making giving the list the height of all the items combined. This won't be an option because I need to load data from an API that paginates the results (15 results per API call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CoordinatorLayout` and `Recyclerview` to achieve this. Or you can add the top view as header to `RecyclerView` instead of using recyclerview in `ScrollView` which does not work as intended until you fix the height of the `RecyclerView`

**UPDATE :**

Please follow this [link](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en) for sample implementations using design library.

Comment: How would I achieve this by using a CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: Went for the header approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want use the `LinearLayout` with the text and image as a header view inside the `RecyclerView` and drop the `ScrollView`.

This post explains how to create a header view in a `RecyclerView`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/4605725