# Grouping recycler-view items by date?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to group my recycler-view data based on a date and show some dividers in between each group as shown below.

--Item #1--

--Item #2--

```
 -- January 2016(Divider)--
```

--item #3--

--item #4--

--item #5--

```
-- December 2015(Divider)--
```

--item #6--

--item #7--

....
  ....

**how I can accomplish this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to have two ViewTypes like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6386583)

You might also want to take a look at [this library](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058) and if you want it to be expandable and sexy you could take a look at [Advanced RecyclerView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1432) library.

Comment: thank you, I was stuck thinking about using itemdecoration. but use two View Types was the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first sort them based on the date.

then use either view_type ([Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview)) as @G.K mentioned or use any recycler header library to set them as sticky headers.

try this : https://github.com/ShamylZakariya/StickyHeaders