# Android: Error inflating a custom RecyclerView inside a Framework

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm having the following error while inflating a custom view component:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class .ScrollableRecyclerView
```

In line 68 inside **TabFragment.java**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
```

Full log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: br.com.osupernerd.osupernerd, PID: 1048
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class br.com.osupernerd.osn.components.ScrollableRecyclerView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                      at br.com.osupernerd.osn.fragments.TabFragment.onCreateView(TabFragment.java:68)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1643)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1272)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3083)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2683)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1928)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1524)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7520)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**ScrollableRecyclerView** The class below is a custom **RecyclerView**, in the future it will implement some resources to control scroll parameters. For test purposes the *init()* method prints a log when it's ready.

This class will implement a custom view to "Pull to Refresh" and controller it inside RecyclerView.

```
public class ScrollableRecyclerView extends RecyclerView
{
    private static final String TAG = "ScrollableRecyclerView";

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private RelativeLayout refreshView;
    private TextView refreshViewText;
    private ImageView refreshViewIcon;
    private ProgressBar refreshViewProgress;

    public ScrollableRecyclerView ( Context context )
    { super( context ); init( context ); }

    public ScrollableRecyclerView ( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
    { super( context, attrs ); init( context ); }

    public ScrollableRecyclerView ( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle )
    { super( context, attrs, defStyle ); init( context ); }

    public void init ( Context context )
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        refreshView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate ( R.layout.refresh_header, this, false );

        refreshViewText = (TextView) refreshView.findViewById ( R.id.refresh_text );
        refreshViewIcon = (ImageView) refreshView.findViewById ( R.id.refresh_icon );
        refreshViewProgress = (ProgressBar) refreshView.findViewById ( R.id.refresh_progress );

        addView ( refreshView );

        Log.d( TAG, "Ready...");
    }

}
```

**TabFragment** Here, it's the **Fragment** that will have **ScrollableRecyclerView** custom component. It's important to say that nothing wrong is happening between MainActivity and TabFragment.

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment implements IHTTPCallback
{
    public final String TAG = "osn.TabFragment";

    private ScrollableRecyclerView recyclerView;

    public TabFragment ()
    {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);

        this.recyclerView = (ScrollableRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.posts_view);
        this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( getContext() ) );

        return view;
}
```

Here is **tab_fragment.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <br.com.osupernerd.osn.components.ScrollableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/posts_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </br.com.osupernerd.osn.components.ScrollableRecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is **refresh_header.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/refresh_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >    
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/refresh_progress"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_down"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
        android:text="@string/refresh_tap_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OBSERVATIONS**

When I use **RecyclerView** instead **ScrollableRecyclerView**... all works well!

When I remove the following code below, from **ScrollableRecyclerView**... all works well!

```
refreshView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate ( R.layout.refresh_header, this, false );

refreshViewText = (TextView) refreshView.findViewById ( R.id.refresh_text );
refreshViewIcon = (ImageView) refreshView.findViewById ( R.id.refresh_icon );
refreshViewProgress = (ProgressBar) refreshView.findViewById ( R.id.refresh_progress );

addView ( refreshView );
```

Someone can help and say what's going wrong? If I can't inflate the component ScrollableRecyclerView, how can I dynamically insert a view inside its?

Comment: Recyclerview is already scrollable. What's this class do?

Comment: Anyways, show the full logcat please

Comment: @cricket_007 This class will implement a custom view to "Pull to Refresh" and controller it inside RecyclerView, also will control "load more" function at some scroll point.

Comment: @cricket_007 and I updated with the full logcat!

Comment: So, you're saying the error only occurs when you inflate a view within your other view? Not too sure - haven't used custom views too much. I was expected the logcat to be more helpful

Comment: do you have any  `Caused by: ` on the logcat?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, the error only occurs when I inflate inside ScrollableRecyclerView class, I don't know if it's a problem with RecyclerView maybe...

Comment: @pskink there's no `Caused by:` on the logcat

Comment: so just for testing place your `inflater.inflate` in `try / catch InflateException` and call `e.printStackTrace` or `Log.d` with `e.getCause()`

Comment: I do think it's strange you inflate a layout with `layout_height="fill_parent"` into a vertical list. That's probably not the problem, though

Comment: @cricket_007 it's the initiable form, I will control this layout height in ScrollableRecyclerView. It will begin as fill_parent while there is no data.

Comment: @pskink I got `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager`. It's strange because I've setted LayoutManager to it in the TabFramework.

Comment: so add a breakpoint in `ScrollableRecyclerView#init` and go step-by-step

Comment: but i think your exception comes from `addView ( refreshView );`

Comment: @pskink it goes to InflateException after `refreshView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate ( R.layout.refresh_header, this, false );` line... Then I did the following: I added `if ( this.getLayoutManager () == null ) { this.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( context ) ); }` inside `ScrollableRecyclerView#init` and I removed `this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( getContext() ) );` from `TabFragment#onCreateView`. Now there is no error... but the recyclerView isn't added into ScrollableRecyclerView.

Comment: @pskink I also think the problem is `addView ( refreshView );` because RecyclerView needs a ViewHolder, but I don't know how to insert refreshView inside ScrollableRecyclerView

Comment: If you are trying to add a header view, this post looks good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you!