# (Nested)ScrollView and RecyclerView responding to each other

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-nestedscrollview

I have a slight issue with scrolling on a screen. Layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/my_account_parent_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       <!--- Views omitted --->
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_account_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is that the recyclerview cannot be in a Scrollview/NestedScrollView thats why its outside the scrollview. Now i need the views that are wrapped in the LinearLayout which is wrapped around the the NestedScrollView to scroll upwards when the user scrolls on any of the views (RecyclerView and All the others above it). Even though the other views have a scrollview wrapped around them, they dont realise that they can scroll out the screen even though the recyclerview has content outside the screen?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your complete xml file containing the layout ??

Comment: @SurajMakhija done

Comment: Alright, that's good

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not a good practice to add `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` but you can add a custom header to the recyclerView.

Follow this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview)

Its a good SO post for adding a header to your RecyclerView.

So here you can add the `LinearLayout` which is inside your `ScrollView` as the first child (header) of your recyclerview and then i suppose it should work as you desire it to!

Which will make you final layout for that screen only this:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_account_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Where the LinearLayout will be inflated in the adapter of the RV as per the post!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CoordinatorLayout` and `app:layout_scrollFlags` . When recyclerview scroll up, layout inside `AppBarLayout` will scroll up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/my_account_parent_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_account_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```