# RecyclerView + ImageView scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` and an `ImageView` that is located under that `RecyclerView`

Here's the relevant xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/upArrow">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<!-- TODO: This view should be part of the recyclerview scroll, we should find a solution for this -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/upArrow"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_up_triangle_vector"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I would like to achieve the following scrolling effect:

When there is an attempt to scroll the `RecyclerView` and/or the `ImageView` below it, the `RecyclerView` will scroll accordingly, and the imageview will stay at its original place.
Basically what I'm trying to achieve is expanding the `RecyclerView` scrolling boundaries to include all the `Imageview`'s height

I was thinking about setting a `ScrollView` that wraps both of these views but I'm not really sure what to do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<!-- TODO: This view should be part of the recyclerview scroll, we should find a solution for this -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/upArrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_up_triangle_vector"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What this code does is it places your RecyclerView on top of your ImageView and the padding at bottom is used to show the image at bottom. Change Height of the ImageView and Padding of the RecyclerView accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You already have got some down-votes in your question I see. I suppose those are for your question which is not actually clear and the solution you're trying to achieve is not the proper way of doing so too.

From your code of the layout, I have come to understand that you need an up arrow button which will scroll to the top of the `RecyclerView` when clicked on it and you want the button to stay in the bottom of the page you're in. You want your `RecyclerView` to scroll as it is and the arrow button to stay where it is. If this is your case, then you need to rethink about the layout and the `Activity` flow design. You need to make the `RecyclerView` and the arrow button completely disjoint.

So, based on my assumption on your question, you need an `Activity` which contains a floating action button and holds a `Fragment`. The `Fragment` will have the `RecyclerView` making the floating action button (for the up arrow) and the `RecyclerView` completely disjoint.

So you need to have an `Activity` and the layout of the `Activity` should look like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `onCreate` function of the `Activity` should look like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mFabUpArrow = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_up);
    mFabUpArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jumpToTopOfTheRecyclerView();
        }
    });

    // Now launch the Fragment from here. 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new RecyclerViewFragment()).commit();
}
```

Now the `RecyclerViewFragment` should have the following layout holding the `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/your_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I think you already know how to populate your `RecyclerView` and do that thing in your `Fragment`.

You might be asking how to implement the `jumpToTopOfTheRecyclerView()` function in the `Activity`. Its simple and you've several option. One approach might be having a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Fragment` and sending the broadcast from your `Activity` which is not so good approach. You might find something very easy to communicate between your `Activity` and your `Fragment`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can just place your header and your RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/upArrow">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/upArrow"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_up_triangle_vector"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and in Java code make  mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); to scroll correctly credits
[check this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview/42388743#42388743)