# Recyclerview within a Scrollview dont coordinate

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have this activity design, which shows a card view inside a `scrollView`, But under that `cardview` I need to put a `listview` or `recyclerview`. The problem is that I need the scroll of that list to coordinate with the main scroll. Osea that when lower in the content the `cardview` will disappear and the list of the `recyclerview` or listview will be crossed.

I need all the content to respond to the main scroll to show up and disappear after `titlebar`, Which should I change or redesign?

[image: Captura de Imagen]

```
        <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/post_coordinator"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/default_profile" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hot_black"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/post_bg"
                android:tint="#FFF"
                />

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/post_bg"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
                app:civ_border_color="#FFF"
                app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                />


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hot_black"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/post_bg"
                android:tint="#FFF"
                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Prepare your Anus Cersei Lanister, You Gonna Die"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/emilia"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/post_comments"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You shouldn't put one scroll view within another. i.e: `ListView` within `ScrollView`. If you have to then use `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 2):

Add your recyclerview inside NestedScrollview. 
Also add recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Use android:fillViewport="true" to your ScrollView. ListView that located inside ScrollView works properly.

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting the `CardView` inside the `RecyclerView` as a **header**, and then you don't need the top `ScrollView`, the card and the list items would all be scrollable within the `RecyclerView`.

There are many ways to add a header to a `RecyclerView`, see here:
[Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview)