# addHeaderView or addFooterView not available in Recycler VIew

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I was trying to design my screen as of same in `Swiggy App`. First, it has horizontal recycler or horizontal scroll view.

Second, it has tab bar which will stick on the top once we will scroll up. Third, it has a vertical recycler view or maybe listView showing restaurants.
So, if we have vertical `listView`, it's very easy to stick that tab bar(view, the second thing on screen) on the top.

You can see an example here: https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-listview-parallax-effect-with-a-sticky

But in case of `RecyclerView`, it doesn't have any direct method `addHeaderView`. So how do we implement this with `RecyclerView`.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/5110595)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, it gives you a header space not working fine. It just adds a space for the header on the top of the list. But doesn't move that sticky header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview)

Answer (score -1):

Use getItemViewType method and create three view holders for first, middle and last items.

[RecyclerView with multiple view type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: you can't answer with a link to another answer.

Comment: Even if this question is possible duplicate and it'll be enough to read that one?