# How to use SwipeRefreshLayout and imageView into NestedScrollView in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-nestedscrollview

In my application i want use `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `imageView` into `NestedScrollView`

I write below codes, but when run application show me **many la**g when scroll `RecyclerView` and **i'm not scroll items**.

**My xml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/banner_layout" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**My java codes:**

```
list.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
list.setHasFixedSize(true);
list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
list.setAdapter(todayRecyclerAdapter);
```

How can i fix it and use this views?

Comment: try to give linear layout some hardcoded height like 200 dp..

Comment: @abhi20392, can you send to me code with my codes?

Comment: see my answer and tell me if it working for you or not

Comment: try with `linearLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)`

Comment: @AvinashKumar, not work me :( please help me

Comment: why are you using NestedScrollView it can be done with RecylerView only using viewType . And place  RecylerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: your codes are fine, check if you have **recyclerview single item with big image or others problems...**

Comment: @Rahul, I want show imageView above of recyclerView and when scroll recyclerView items, scroll this imageView. how can i it?

Comment: @AvinashKumar, I want show imageView above of recyclerView and when scroll recyclerView items, scroll this imageView. how can i it?

Comment: @Drckeck refer this ans  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/6382210. you need to add header to recylerView that's it

Comment: @Rahul, thanks dear rahul. but i should fill recyclerview with one api and i should fill imageView with another api! how can i it? i can fill recyclerView header with another Api? !!

Comment: @Drckeck you can combine both api data into ArrayList the zero position of list can be header itself rest is your data

Comment: @Rahul, can you send to me code with your answer ? thanks my friend

Comment: @Drckeck You do not have to change your code as i said it is working like charm, Have a look of [SOURCE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ozBoX9Yl-oDyusVfL23X0k6VtrphPABq/view?usp=sharing)  and [APK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LATKgF5xT_JB6GDAJtVvX90z8WQuZHsb/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

Avoid nested scrolling whenever possible .
You can design layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

You can define data of adapter like this

```
.............
List<Object> objects=new ArrayList<>()
object.add(new ImageData('Image url'))
object.add(new Data('title','subtitle','date'))
.............
```

Since `RecylerView` adapter supports different `viewType`s you can use first position of adapter as 
header  view type and rest normal view type.
For that you can refer to this ans 
[Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview/26573338#26573338) 
For a dynamic header, you can create a method like :

```
----
setHeaderAvailable(boolean isHeaderAvailable){
  this.isHeaderAvailable=isHeaderAvailable
}
----
```

and adapter data will look like this:

```
---
  List<Object> objects=new ArrayList<>()
  if(imageUrl!=null){
  adapter.setHeaderAvailable(true)
  object.add(new ImageData('Image url'))
}else{
  adapter.setHeaderAvailable(false)
}
   object.add(new Data('title','subtitle','date'))
--
```

and update `getItemViewType` method like this:

```
----
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if (isPositionHeader(position) && isHeaderAvailable)
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
 }
---
```

Comment: Thanks, but some times we have not image and i want gone this image! how can i it? can i dynamically set header and when image is empty gone this imageview (header)?

Comment: didn't get you ?

Comment: This header not show always. if has image from another api then show this header, else not show this header . i want this

Comment: Thanks , please help me my dear friend. i really need your help. yhanks

Answer (score 0):

replace your RecyclerView with this one..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Comment: you don't need to set this property try to remove this 
 list.setHasFixedSize(true);

Answer (score 0):

You have set this property before `setAdapter`

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks , but first see my post. i say add this code in java : `list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`
`list.setAdapter(todayRecyclerAdapter);` and again not work me

Comment: Alright. do like this.and let me know.
1). fix the height of `recyclerview`
2). use `ScrollVIew` instead of `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <CoordinatorLayout>
   <SwipeRefreshLayout>
       <RecyclerView>  

            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

       <Appbarlayout>

              <Toolbar>

               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"/>

       <Relative Layout>

             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"/>

           <ImageView>

              </Relative Layout>

      </Appbarlayout>
       </SwipeRefreshLayout> 
         </CoordinatorLayout>

         Please try in these way it will work.
```

Comment: I want show imageView above of recyclerView and when scroll recyclerView items, scroll this imageView. how can i it?