# How to display records per line with table header in Android?

Tags: android

I have a `List<MLog>` from a database with three fields, I hope to display the data as a table with table header just like the following image. How can I do? Thanks!

It seems that RecyclerView don't fit to do that. RecyclerView support only LinearLayoutManager and GridLayoutManager.

**Image**

[image]

```
class LogAdapter (val logItemList: List<MLog>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LogAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LogAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_log_recycleview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LogAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(logItemList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return logItemList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(aMLog: MLog) {
            itemView.tvName.text=aMLog.name
            itemView.tvStatus.text=aMLog.status
            itemView.tvNote.text=aMLog.note

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you make columns within the LinearLayoutManager?

Comment: Thanks! I can't add table header in  LinearLayoutManager, if I add table header outsider RecyclerView, sometimes the position can't be alignment

Comment: You could try putting a TableLayout or GridLayout within each row / the header. Make the columns stretch to fit the screen. However, it might be better UX design just to show a simple row of `name: note` and color each row based on the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` supports multiple view type. [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) will help you to implement multiple view type like itemview, headerview, footerview.

From documentation :

> Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.
>
> The default implementation of this method returns 0, making the
>   assumption of a single view type for the adapter. Unlike ListView
>   adapters, types need not be contiguous. Consider using id resources to
>   uniquely identify item view types.

Then you have to check the viewType in [onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) method. Depending on the viewType you will create different `ViewHolder`.

**Sample Code:**

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        } else if (isPositionFooter(position)) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }

       return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

   private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private boolean isPositionFooter(int position) {
        return position > mList.size();
    }


      @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout,
                    viewGroup, false);
            return new FooterViewHolder(view);

        }

        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");

    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


       if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {

            //set the Value from List to corresponding UI component as shown below.
            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).txtName.setText(mList.get(position))

            //similarly bind other UI components or perform operations

        }else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {


             // Your code here

        }else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {

             //your code here
        }


    }


     @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // Add two more counts to accomodate header and footer
        return this.mList.size() + 2;
    }
```

Check [this](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/recyclerview-header-footer-pagination/#.Wve4ohy-lBQ) tutorial.
Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573338/1292557) too.