# Get error when trying to add custom header for recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add `header` to my recylerview so that it will look like `<thead>` (in HTML table). So, I'm following this tutorial https://en.proft.me/2017/11/25/how-add-custom-header-recylerview/

> Here is my adapter

```
public class Sales_header_adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Sales_header_model> salesheaderlist;

    public Sales_header_adapter(List<Sales_header_model> salesheaderlist) {
        this.salesheaderlist = salesheaderlist;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if(viewType == ListHeader.TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sales_header_rec_header, parent, false);
            return  new VHHeader(v);
        } else if(viewType == ListHeader.TYPE_ITEM) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sales_header_rec, parent, false);
            return new VHItem(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof VHHeader) {
            Header header = salesheaderlist.get(position);
            VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader)holder;
            VHheader.nonota_h.setText(header.getNoNota());
            VHheader.tanggal_h.setText(header.getTanggalTransaksi());
            VHheader.total_h.setText("Rp. 0");
            VHheader.outlet_h.setText(header.getOutletCode());

        } else if(holder instanceof VHItem) {
            Sales_header_model as =  salesheaderlist.get(position);
            VHItem VHitem = (VHItem)holder;
            VHitem.nonota.setText(as.getNoNota());
            VHitem.tanggal.setText(as.getTanggalTransaksi());
            VHitem.total.setText("Rp. 0");
            VHitem.outlet.setText(as.getOutletCode());
        }

    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView outlet_h, tanggal_h, total_h,nonota_h;
        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            outlet_h            = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tanggalnota);
            tanggal_h           = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
            total_h             = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nonota);
            nonota_h            = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outletcode);
        }

    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView outlet, tanggal, total,nonota;
        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tanggal         =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tanggalnota);
            total           =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
            nonota          = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nonota);
            outlet          = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outletcode);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return salesheaderlist.get(position).getItemType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return salesheaderlist.size();
    }

}
```

> and here is my `sales_header_model`

```
public class Sales_header_model  implements ListHeader {

    String OutletCode,TanggalTransaksi,NoNota,CreatedBy,Seller;
    String CreatedDate;
    Integer Status;


    public Sales_header_model(String outletCode, String tanggalTransaksi, String noNota, String createdby, String Seller, String CreatedDate, Integer Status) {
        this.OutletCode = outletCode;
        this.TanggalTransaksi = tanggalTransaksi;
        this.NoNota = noNota;
        this.CreatedBy = createdby;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.Seller = Seller;
        this.CreatedDate = CreatedDate;
    }

    public String getOutletCode() {
        return OutletCode;
    }

    public void setOutletCode(String outletCode) {
        OutletCode = outletCode;
    }

    public String getTanggalTransaksi() {
        return TanggalTransaksi;
    }

    public void setTanggalTransaksi(String tanggalTransaksi) {
        TanggalTransaksi = tanggalTransaksi;
    }

    public String getNoNota() {
        return NoNota;
    }

    public void setNoNota(String noNota) {
        NoNota = noNota;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return CreatedBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        CreatedBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getSeller() {
        return Seller;
    }

    public void setSeller(String seller) {
        Seller = seller;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return CreatedDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        CreatedDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public Sales_header_model() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemType() {
        return ListHeader.TYPE_HEADER;
    }
}
```

> My `header` class

```
public class Header implements ListHeader {

    String OutletCode,TanggalTransaksi,NoNota,Seller;

    public String getOutletCode() {
        return OutletCode;
    }

    public void setOutletCode(String outletCode) {
        OutletCode = outletCode;
    }

    public String getTanggalTransaksi() {
        return TanggalTransaksi;
    }

    public void setTanggalTransaksi(String tanggalTransaksi) {
        TanggalTransaksi = tanggalTransaksi;
    }

    public String getNoNota() {
        return NoNota;
    }

    public void setNoNota(String noNota) {
        NoNota = noNota;
    }

    public String getSeller() {
        return Seller;
    }

    public void setSeller(String seller) {
        Seller = seller;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemType() {
        return ListHeader.TYPE_HEADER;
    }

}
```

> and the listener `ListHeader`

```
public interface ListHeader {

    int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    int TYPE_HEADER = 1;

    int getItemType();
}
```

> The error part is in

```
if(holder instanceof VHHeader) {

            Header header = salesheaderlist.get(position);
            VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader)holder;
            VHheader.nonota_h.setText(header.getNoNota());
            VHheader.tanggal_h.setText(header.getTanggalTransaksi());
            VHheader.total_h.setText("Rp. 0");
            VHheader.outlet_h.setText(header.getOutletCode());

 }
```

> and here is my error message

error: incompatible types: Sales_header_model cannot be converted to Header

How can i fix it ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You missed the casting part written in the tutorial. I have added the comments on those parts that you need to change.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        //cast the item to respective type
        Header header = (Header) salesheaderlist.get(position);
        VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader)holder;
        VHheader.nonota_h.setText(header.getNoNota());
        VHheader.tanggal_h.setText(header.getTanggalTransaksi());
        VHheader.total_h.setText("Rp. 0");
        VHheader.outlet_h.setText(header.getOutletCode());

    } else if(holder instanceof VHItem) {
        //cast the item to respective type
        Sales_header_model as =  (Sales_header_model) salesheaderlist.get(position);
        VHItem VHitem = (VHItem)holder;
        VHitem.nonota.setText(as.getNoNota());
        VHitem.tanggal.setText(as.getTanggalTransaksi());
        VHitem.total.setText("Rp. 0");
        VHitem.outlet.setText(as.getOutletCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: I still have same error. Please tell me if you have another solution for what i want to achieve

Comment: hi thanks for trying to helping me, i already fix my prbolem with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview/26573338#26573338