# Pulling RecyclerView to show a view above it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**What I'm trying to do:**

i have a `RecyclerView` and i want to behave in such a way that when its pulled, a `view` becomes `visible` `above` it. `Telegram App` is a really good example of this.

[image]

**More details:**

1.the `view` should have `animation` when it's becoming visible, slowly expanding while the `user` is pulling the `recyclerview`

2.the `view` should become `invisible` when `recyclerview` is `scrolled` `down`.

**My Code:**

XML code of the fragment that contains the `view` and the `recyclerview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_story_library_main_layout"
    tools:context=".fragment.StoryLibraryFragment">
    <View
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/test_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_story_library"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_below="@id/test_view"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't think any other code is needed, if not please say so in the comments so i add the required code.

**What I've tried:**

i tried to use [RecyclerViewBouncy](https://github.com/chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android) for this effect. i used a `ScrollListener` to get the amount of `pulling` `user` is doing to dynamically set the `height` of the `view`.
but it was too messy and it didn't work properly.

how can I achieve this? if you know any guide please share, even a clue would suffice :)

Comment: Someone has already done it using [Item Decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458426/15298643)

Comment: what you are referring to is a parallax effect, what I'm trying to do is kind of different because user needs to pull to make the ```view``` visible