# Scroll problem with Textbox and RecyclerView - Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

I am having a Linearlayout which is having a Textview and the Recyclerview.
The problem is that when RecyclerView's data is increased then when we scroll, the Textview above the recyclerview keeps it position i.e. not scrolled and only RecyclerView's contents are scrolled.
I want whole screen to be scroll instead of only RecyclerView scrolling.

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView/>
  <RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use ItemDecoration as shown in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458426/10429259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `NestedScrollView` as parent of `LinearLayout` to scroll whole screen.

Try below code:

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```